# Nested angular component not showing errors

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a nested angular component implementet like this:

```
<div>
    <app-nested-component *ngIf="interfaceA.id > 0" [interfaceB]="interfaceB"></app-nested-component>
</div>
```

The component itself is a little bit like this:

nested-component.component.ts

```
import { InterfaceB} from './../../interfaces/interfaceB';
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nested-component',
  templateUrl: './app-nested-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-nested-component.component.css']
})
export class NestedComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() interfaceB: InterfaceB[];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<InterfaceB>;
  displayedColumns: ['colA','colB','colC'];

  constructor() { }
  
  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.interfaceB);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.interfaceB);
    console.log(this.dataSource);
  }
}
```

nested-component.component.html

```
<mat-card-title>
    <h3 class="with-icon"><mat-icon class="header-icon">icon</mat-icon>InterfaceB</h3>
</mat-card-title>
<mat-card-content>
  <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
 
      <ng-container matColumnDef="colA">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ColA</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.colA.name}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="colB">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ColB</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.colB}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="colC">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ColC</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.colC}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
   
      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
  </div>
</mat-card-content>
```

It seems that if I have an error on this nested component it does not shown in console log on web browser (chrome). What would I need to do to have errors written to console for nested components?

Thank you for your help!

Edit:
Added full example code.

Comment: What is your indicator that there's an error? You do realize that you console logs won't execute unless the child component changes state, correct?

Comment: No. The reason why I'm asking is because the data in the table (as the nested component should only show data as table) are not shown. Even if the data itself are present. Because I do not get any error it is hard for me to understand where the issue is.

I do not understand why both console.log code lines are shown up in the console of the web browser but there is no error shown.

Comment: To check if any error is shown by the nested component I created errors on it on my own but these are also not shown on the console log.

Comment: And is `interfaceA.id > 0`?

Comment: yes. The issue still exists also when I remove this condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

Instead

```
displayedColumns: ['colA','colB','colC'];
```

obviously it should be:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['colA','colB','colC'];
```